# Trouble with little o notation.

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics

**Problem:**
Compute the differential of $\phi(t) = e^{A+tB}$ at $0$ where $A$ and $B$ are commuting square matrices of size $n\times n.$

We proceed in the usual manner:
$$\phi(0+h) = e^{A+hB} = e^{A}e^{hB}$$ since $A$ and $hB$ commute. Thus 
$$\phi(h) = e^{A}\left(I+hB+o(hB)\right)$$
$$ = e^A+h e^AB+e^{A}o(hB) = \phi(0)+he^{A}B+o(h).$$
I am not sure why $e^{A}o(hB)$ is $o(h).$ Perhaps someone can explain?

Answer (score 1):

One definition of $o(h)$ is as follows:

> A matrix valued function $f(h)$ is $o(h)$ if $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\|f(h)\|}{h} = 0$ (for some matrix norm $\|\cdot\|$).

With this definition, I think you should find the result easy to prove.

Comment: But the function $f(h)= e^{A}o(hB).$ How do I deal with the $o(hB)$ term?

Comment: The $o(hB)$ term is a stand-in for a function $g(h)$ satisfying
$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\|g(h)\|}{\|hB\|} = 0
$$
However, this is equivalent to saying that $g$ is $o(h)$.  So, we can simply replace $o(hB)$ with $o(h)$.

Comment: Typically, however, I wouldn't use the notation $o(hB)$. Instead, I would say that
$$
e^{hB} = I + hB + o(h)
$$